Cannot read value of type 'Vector3' error in Input System package
I'm a Unity newbie. This time, I'm trying to make the Player operable with an Xbox controller using PlayerInput. However, when I control the player, I get these errors:
Errors that occurred:

[20:35:08] InvalidOperationException: Cannot read value of type 'Vector3' from control '/XinputControllerWindows/leftStick' bound to action 'Player/Move[/XInputControllerWindows/leftStick]'
[20:35:08] InvalidOperationException while execuring 'started' callbacks of 'Player/Move[/XInputControllerWindows/leftStick]'


The version is 2021.3.37f1. The work is made with something called 3D Sample Scene (URP).
PlayerInput

PlayerContoroller
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using Vector2 = UnityEngine.Vector2;
using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;

public class PlayerController_PC : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 move;
    private Vector3 moveForward;
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    private float turnTimeRate = 0.5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rotation();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        Vector3 cameraForward = Vector3.Scale(Camera.main.transform.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
        moveForward = cameraForward * move.z + Camera.main.transform.right * move.x;
        moveForward = moveForward.normalized;

        if (move.magnitude > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = moveForward * moveSpeed * move.magnitude + new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }
    }

    private void Rotation()
    {
        Vector3 cameraForward = Vector3.Scale(Camera.main.transform.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
        moveForward = cameraForward * move.z + Camera.main.transform.right * move.x;
        moveForward = moveForward.normalized;

        if (move.magnitude > 0)
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveForward);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnTimeRate);
        }
        else
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = transform.rotation;
            transform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
    }

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        move = new Vector3(context.ReadValue<Vector3>().x, 0f, context.ReadValue<Vector2>().y);
    }
}


Remember, error messages are not arcane incantations. They are documents communicating what went wrong and giving insight into how to fix it, so read them carefully.
In this case, everything you need to fix this is present in the first error message:

Cannot read value of type 'Vector3' from control... bound to action 'Player/Move[/XInputControllerWindows/leftStick]'

Unity is telling you it doesn't know how to read a Vector3 from the Player/Move control (bound to the left stick).
That makes sense - an analog stick only has two dimensions, x and y; it's not a three-dimensional input method.
So, next we search the code for the text Vector3 anywhere it's reading from the player movement input, and we get an immediate hit:
move = new Vector3(context.ReadValue<Vector3>().x, 0f, context.ReadValue<Vector2>().y);
//                                   Typo ⬆️

So you just have a typo where you wrote Vector3 when you meant to write Vector2.
This code would be slightly more efficient (and shorter) to write this way:
var input = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
move.x = input.x;
move.z = input.y;


Thank you. Thanks to you, it now works normally.

If this worked for you, click the ✅ icon in the upper -left to mark the answer as "Accepted".
